# "unexpected end of file" in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, here-document

I have this if in a bash script:

```
if [ $ACTION = deploy ]; then
    ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java ${JVM_ARGS} weblogic.WLST << EOJ
    connect('XXX','XXX','t3://XXX:8001')
    jndi();
    ls();
    disconnect();
    exit ();
    EOJ
else
    echo "XXX"
fi
```

I think the error is in the EOJ.

Comment: By the way, all those semicolons are unnecessary. The only reason to use them is if you want multiple commands in the same line.

Comment: @BryanGarza Really? Those semicolons aren't in the bash part, they're in the embedded Weblogic part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`EOJ` needs to be fully left-justified, ie. no leading white-space, and no trailing space either. Also, you could/should (depending on your needs) write the first one as `<<'EOJ'` .. the quotes disable some shell expansion which can otherwise occur.

From `info bash`

> Here Documents
>          This type of redirection instructs the shell to  read  input  from  the
>          current source until a line containing only delimiter (with no trailing
>          blanks) is seen.  All of the lines read up to that point are then  used
>          as the standard input for a command.

```
   The format of here-documents is:

          <<[-]word
                  here-document
          delimiter

   No  parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or
   pathname expansion is performed on word.  If any characters in word are
   quoted,  the  delimiter is the result of quote removal on word, and the
   lines in the here-document are not expanded.  If word is unquoted,  all
   lines  of  the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, com‐
   mand substitution, and arithmetic expansion.  In the latter  case,  the
   character  sequence  \<newline> is ignored, and \ must be used to quote
   the characters \, $, and `.

   If the redirection operator is <<-, then all leading tab characters are
   stripped  from  input  lines  and  the line containing delimiter.  This
   allows here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a  natural
   fashion.
```

Comment: That's it! I just needed to move the EOJ. Thanks!